# Ошибка в цикле сдвига

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

я попытался сделать

> Все нечетные строки матрицы сдвинуть циклически на К элементов влево.

но получилось так что оно сдвигает вправо ,в чем моя ошибка ?Прошу прошения если мой вопрос оформлен не правильно ,но я новичок )

```
for(i=1;i<string;i+=2)
{
    for(shift=0;shift<K;shift++)
    {
        tmp=Matrix[i][column-1];
        for(j=column-1;j>0;j--)
        {
            Matrix[i][j]=Matrix[i][j-1];
        }
        Matrix[i][0]=tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что элементу вы присваиваете тот, который слева, т.е. двигаете вправо. А вообще, вы действуете *крайне неэффективно*...

Comment: То есть ошибка в `j-1` а нужно `j+1` верно ?

Comment: ...и поменять направление цикла.

Comment: прошу прошение, но не могу понять какой цикл